# Excluding categories from "Manage Categories" using a get_terms filter

Tags: theme-development

I'm using a filter on get_terms (see below) to remove a specified number of named categories from the "Manage Categories" listing. It works great, however, the excluded categories are still counted in the category count field that's displayed just under the "Search Categories" button.

Is it possible that I can subtract these categories from the count?

```
function admin_edit_tags() {add_filter( 'get_terms', 'admin_trim_category_description', 10, 2 );}

function admin_trim_category_description( $terms, $taxonomies ){
    if( 'category' != $taxonomies[0] )return $terms;
    $my_categories = array('test1','test2','test3');
    foreach( $terms as $key => $term) 
        if(in_array($terms[$key]->name, $my_categories)) { unset($terms[$key]);}
        else
        {
        if(isset($terms[$key]->description) && $terms[$key]->description !=='') $terms[$key]->description = strip_tags(substr( $term->description, 0, 75 ))."...";
        }
        return $terms;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use `get_terms_args` filter instead of `get_terms` and just add exclude arg, so now `get_terms()` function won't retrieve those cats and you'll get right count. Here's code example:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'mamaduka_edit_get_terms_args', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Exclude categories from "Edit Categories" screen
 *
 */
 function mamaduka_edit_get_terms_args( $args, $taxonomies ) {
    if ( is_admin() && 'category' !== $taxonomies[0] )
        return $args;

    $args['exclude'] = array( 8, 10); // Array of cat ids you want to exclude
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mamaduka, I'd really like to use this, however, no matter how many cat ids I place in the array, the Category count remains unchanged at "16 items".

Comment: I tested it on my local dev and it was working just as expected.

Comment: @N2Mystic can you check if my code is running? I tested it on my two local dev installations and it works, not sure what is problem with yours

Comment: @N2Mystic When testing, be sure to turn off all of your plugins (if it's live, go into maintainance mode - or use a plugin for that).

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow the suggestions and let you know. I appreciate the help :)