# How to create a custom sort for WordPress categories

Tags: categories

I have this problem that I am encountering. I am trying to sort my categories to display in the order that I want them to. I have read the WordPress documentation on all of the sort options. However, there is no inclination of how to choose the categories and make them flow the way I want.

This is what the Codex presents:

> **orderby** (string) Sort categories alphabetically or by unique category ID. The default is sort by Category ID. Valid values:
>   - id
>  - name - default
>  - slug
>  - count
>  - term_group
>
> **order** (string) Sort order for categories (either ascending or descending). The default is ascending. Valid values:
>  - asc -
>   default
>  - desc

However, like I said, this does not help me because I need them to display in the order I choose.

Here is the code I am implementing at the moment. Which is in the order that I want them to display.

```
<?php
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'ID',
'order' => 'ASC',
'include' => '5,6,7,8,29,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16'
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) {
echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf(     __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name . '</a>' . ' ' . '(' . $category->count . ')' . '</li> ';
}
?>
```

Comment: This post might help http://www.wphub.com/sorting-categories-custom-sort-order/

Comment: Thank you for that link. I looked at it but it seems like a lot of work and I don't want to really use a plugin either. But I thank you very much for responding so quickly. I am really grateful for the time you took to try and help.

Comment: [This might help](http://quickhow.net/2012/code/how-to-get-posts-using-post-ids-in-the-order-it-was-given-on-wordpress). Although it's for posts but the second solution could be useful for you as it is using php and array.

Answer (score 9):

If you're already using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) (which you should be!) you can create an order field for your categories from which you can set them manually in numerical order.

Then all you have to do is:

```
$categories = get_categories( $args );  

usort($categories, function($a, $b) {
   return get_field("category_order", "category_".$a->term_id) - get_field("category_order", "category_".$b->term_id);
});

foreach ($categories as $category){
...
```

Where `category_order` is the field name you created with ACF.

*Note: Using the PHP 5.3 way of usort.*

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found this plugin that does exactly what I want. I didn't want to use a plugin but this one seemed pretty light weight and it did the job perfectly. http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/

Comment: As of 2021-07-19, it does not reflect the desired sort order on the front-end. Using WordPress 5.7.2 with the Twenty Twenty One theme OOTB

Answer (score 2):

The original code will work if you change the arguments to: `'orderby' => 'include'`

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'include',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'include' => '5,6,7,8,29,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16'
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf(     __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name . '</a>' . ' ' . '(' . $category->count . ')' . '</li> ';
}
```

Comment: yup, that works for me :)