# Is there a way to order categories?

Tags: categories

With regards to ordering categories on a page or post (in breadcrumbs for example) is there a way of ordering these?

I know that there are plugins but I can't seem to get them to work (I've tried two of them).

Surely Wordpress has another means of doing this?

Thanks for all direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'wpse_53094_sort_get_terms_args', 10, 2 );
function wpse_53094_sort_get_terms_args( $args, $taxonomies ) 
{
    global $pagenow;
    if( !is_admin() || ('post.php' != $pagenow && 'post-new.php' != $pagenow) ) 
            return $args;

    $args['orderby'] = 'slug';
    $args['order'] = 'DESC';

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: wow - thats interesting...

So 10, 2 are examples of category ID's right?

Comment: you can refer this link [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53094/how-to-change-the-categories-order-in-the-admin-dashboard)

Comment: 10 is priority & 2 is accepted arguments

Comment: Accept the answer if u find it useful :)  so it will also helpful for others.